# Why do I get an "Expected body of lambda expression" in the NSMutableArray?

Tags: nsmutablearray

I got the below code and I am not sure why I am getting the "Expected body of lambda expression" error.

binImg is a UIImage and contours is a vector from openCV (std::vector > contours;).

```
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [binImg, contours];
```

Can I not put a vector into an array or is there a syntax issue. Please enlighten me - thanks

Comment: after researching this in more detail I am pretty sure that it is not possible to store a vector in an NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to store a contour in an NSMutableArray.